# prediction student performance using conventional neural network CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to do an experiment to predict student performance using Deep Learning.  We can try applying these models and compare the accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 score. (Also, we can try only fully connected NN to be used as a baseline)

1. CNN with one dimension as the input
2. Fully connected, followed by CNN
3. CNN followed by Fully connected followed by CNN.

I preprocessed the dataset to be suitable for the classification problem (pass/fail); the below code only the first model

1. I Want to check whether it is correct or not:
   `X_train`, `y_train`, `y_test`, `X_test`
   Input shape, numbers of neurons on each layer, and the number of neurons at the output layer.
2. I want to make sure the code is correct before I proceed with something else.

X_train.shape. (730, 56)
X_test.shape.  (314, 56)

```
# CNN 

#importing the required libraries
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

#reshaping data

X_train = X_train.values.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1],1))

X_test = X_test.values.reshape((X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))

#checking the shape after reshaping
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

#normalizing the pixel values
X_train=X_train/255
X_test=X_test/255
```

output:

```
(730, 56, 1)
(314, 56, 1)
```

```
#defining model
model1=Sequential()

#part 1 CNN with one dimension as input 

#adding convolution layer
model1.add(Conv1D(32,3, activation='relu', padding='same', 
                 input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],1)))

#adding pooling layer
model1.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))


#adding fully connected layer
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))

#adding fully connected layer
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))


#adding output layer
model1.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

#compiling the model
model1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model1.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)            (None, 56, 32)            128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_5 (MaxPooling1 (None, 28, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 896)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 128)               114816    
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 130       
=================================================================
Total params: 123,330
Trainable params: 123,330
Non-trainable params: 0
```

fitting the model and evaluate it

```
#fitting the model
history = model1.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32 ,epochs=50 ,verbose=1)

#evaluting the model
_, accuracy = model1.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print('Accuracy:%.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

output:

```
Train on 730 samples
Epoch 1/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 292us/sample - loss: 0.0851 - acc: 0.9836
Epoch 2/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 282us/sample - loss: 0.0795 - acc: 0.9808
Epoch 3/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 294us/sample - loss: 0.0776 - acc: 0.9836
Epoch 4/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 291us/sample - loss: 0.0873 - acc: 0.9795
Epoch 5/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 287us/sample - loss: 0.0893 - acc: 0.9726
Epoch 6/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 292us/sample - loss: 0.0997 - acc: 0.9712
Epoch 7/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 288us/sample - loss: 0.0871 - acc: 0.9808
Epoch 8/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 295us/sample - loss: 0.0853 - acc: 0.9740
Epoch 9/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 300us/sample - loss: 0.0796 - acc: 0.9767
Epoch 10/50
730/730 [==============================] -
.............
............ 
Epoch 50/50
730/730 [==============================] - 0s 315us/sample - loss: 0.0857 - acc: 0.9685
314/314 [==============================] - 0s 180us/sample - loss: 1.9087 - acc: 0.6943
Accuracy:69.43
```

Comment: What's the label distribution in your train and test sets? It seems like it's making predictions without regards to the input.

Comment: X_train.shape.  is (730, 56)  and X_test.shape. (314, 56). . Number of instances is 1044, and the number of attributes are 33, but after converting them to numeric values, it becomes 1044 X 56

Comment: What are the counts of the labels (i.e. pass or fail) though? It seems that your training set is very skewed.

Comment: do you mean the number of students who pass and fail? from all dataset pass 714 and fail 330